# I want to add new rows when add button is pressed, and with each added row a delete button should come to delete the row

Tags: vue.js

This is my code in which I have defined a table

```
<table v-if="Object.keys(content_state).length >= 1" class="editable-table" id="table_value">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="editable-tabidle-header">Field</th>
                                            <th class="editable-table-header">Value</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr v-for="(pageDataItem, idx) in content_state" :key="idx" class="editable-table-row">
                                            <td class="editable-table-data">
                                                <div>{{pageDataItem.modified_keyword}}</div>

                                            </td>
                                            <td class="editable-table-data">
                                                 <div>
                                                    <b-form-input v-model="pageDataItem.formatted_text" @click="input_form($event)" id= "'pageDataItem.modified_keyword + idx'" :style="{'border': '2px solid rgb(' + 
                          pageDataItem.color[0] + ',' + pageDataItem.color[1] + ',' +
                          pageDataItem.color[2] + ')', 'border-radius': '4px'}" v-on:dblclick="showModal($event, 0)" plaintext ></b-form-input>
                                                </div>
                                               <b-btn variant="success" @click="Add(id)" id="Add-button">Add</b-btn>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

And Javascript code is

```
 public AddRow(id:any)
   {
        console.log(id)
        var x =1;
        let d = document.getElementById(id);
        console.log(id)
        let clone = d.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
        clone.value = '';
        clone.id= id+x; 


        this.last_added_row = clone.id;      
        d.appendChild(clone);
    }
```

How should I add delete button with each new row generated? There should only be one add button per row and as many delete buttons as the input box.

Comment: Could you add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Some of your HTML is broken.

Comment: umm.. can you tell me where html is broken? Because this is the part where I need to make changes

Comment: In line 12 is a closing tag that doesn't have a corresponding opening tag. Similarly, line 20 has a opening tag which doesn't get closed. I'd guess this is some copy-paste mistake, but every IDE should usually catch this.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It was my mistake. I have corrected the code, Much appreciated.

Comment: Could you still provide a minimal, reproducible example and tell us where your difficulties are, and what you already tried? Adding new rows should be as easy as adding elements to the `content_state` array, and given you're already using `v-for`, I'm unsure what exactly you're having problems with.

Comment: Is this `content_state` a simple object or is it coming from Vuex? As @CGundlach said, you just need to add the new row to this object. If it is coming from Vuex, you need to dispatch an action then.

Comment: Yes, I got that part. content_state is a simple object where for each key I can have multiple input box(basically here I need to add row).

Comment: But I dont want the whole row. I want to add or delete a input box to a specific key